# DOM not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm not sure why, but before similar code was working. Now, The server restarted, and the code will not work at all. I have isolated the problem in the code below to something wrong with the DOM, specifically the div with id "thumbnails". I could not change the innerHTML of the div no matter what, even in Google Chrome's console (with document.getElementById("thumbnails").innerHTML). The div is empty (the p tag with "hi" is removed), and variable "output" is set to what it is supposed to be (not blank). Anyone know why?

If you want to test it yourself, go to [quantumquantonium.ddns.net/images_and_videos/screenshots/](http://quantumquantonium.ddns.net/images_and_videos/screenshots/)

```
<h1>Screenshots</h1>
<div id = "thumbnails" align = "center"><p>hi</p></div>
<div class="gallery" align="center">
    <img name="preview" id="preview" alt=""></img>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var output;
function update(){
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                console.log("readystate = 4");
                output = xhttp.responseText;
                console.log(output);
                document.getElementById("thumbnails").innerHTML = output;
            }
    }
}
function sendInfo(){
    xhttp.open("GET","http://quantumquantonium.ddns.net/images_and_videos/screenshots/php.php" ,true);
    xhttp.send();
    update();
}

sendInfo();
</script>
```

Comment: not sure if the spacing between `id = "thumbnails"` is causing your issue but it looks pretty bad

Comment: A likely culprit is the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). Unless `http://quantumquantonium.ddns.net` is also where this page is hosted, it will be limited if not restricted from making requests to it. Check your browser's developer tools for any errors.

Comment: @TimOgilvy: That [is valid HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0).

Comment: Please show us what exactly the content of `output` is. Best, do `console.log` it right there to be sure yourself. The observed behaviour suggests that the DOM works fine but `output` is an empty string.

Comment: @TimOgilvy White spaces are ignored in HTML

Comment: The question title might not be the most appropriate one :/ I think it's too vague

Comment: @Jonathan Lonowski go to [link](quantumquantonium.ddns.net/images_and_videos/screenshots) to test it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not in code you are using it is in data coming back from server, it has **invalid HTML**(`double(")` and `single quotes(')` are not balanced and *you should use double quotes to delimit  attribute values in html*) some part of markup is here:

```
<img onmouseover= " preview.src='2015-01-25_00004.jpg" name=2015-01-25_00004.jpg src=2015-01-25_00004.jpg alt='' style = 'width:50px;height:50px;>
<img onmouseover= " preview.src='2015-01-25_00006.jpg" name=2015-01-25_00006.jpg src=2015-01-25_00006.jpg alt='' style = 'width:50px;height:50px;>   
<img onmouseover= " preview.src='2015-01-29_00003.jpg" name=2015-01-29_00003.jpg src=2015-01-29_00003.jpg alt='' style = 'width:50px;height:50px;>
<img onmouseover= " preview.src='2015-01-29_00004.jpg" name=2015-01-29_00004.jpg src=2015-01-29_00004.jpg alt='' style = 'width:50px;height:50px;>
```

Correct your html that it is; ;)

You can try this html format:

```
<img onmouseover="preview.src='2015-01-29_00004.jpg'" name="2015-01-29_00004.jpg" src="2015-01-29_00004.jpg" alt="" style="width:50px; height:50px;">
```

Comment: Thanks, but where might the error in the html be? And why isn't errored HTML printed in the DOM? Does it refuse to print with an HTML error?

Comment: Because this is an html parsing error so browser don't warn for this and if it would be a JavaScript error browser would warn;

Comment: @AndyHerbert Missing closing quotes for each `style` attribute and for the string in each `onmouseover`.

Comment: I found the error. At the end of the img tags, I was missing a quote. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @AndyHerbert `name` attributes do not have quotes surrounding value

Answer (score 1):

That bunch of

```
<img onmouseover= " preview.src='2015-01-25_00004.jpg" name=2015-01-25_00004.jpg src=2015-01-25_00004.jpg alt='' style = 'width:50px;height:50px;>
```

tags you are getting from your API is *heavily malformed*. No wonder that the HTML parser scraps them altogether and leaves you with an empty DOM.